"No suitable python runtime found" When using WikiTeam tools
I am a newb to python and coding in general. But I want to datahoard lol
So I've been trying to use dumpgenerator.py to create a copy of ck 3's wiki https://ck3.paradoxwikis.com/api.php using these instructions https://github.com/WikiTeam/wikiteam/wiki/Tutorial#I_have_no_shell_access_to_server
but I keep getting the error "No suitable python runtime found" when trying to execute the program from the cmd with admin privileges in the programs directory. I have python 3.12 installed using the installer version. screen cap of the error
I reinstalled python and messed with the Path environmental variables moving stuff up and down to see if anything changed. Nothing happened.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This can be any number of reasons. Either python is not added to your PATH environment variable so its .exe it is not recognized at command line, python is installed for a different user on machine, python is installed on different 32/64- bit architecture than the shell you run...
